# Calling non-existent String.config method in mysql module (related to async code)

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I am encountering in my project a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined` error. It turns out that this error is thrown at the following snippet in the code for the `mysql` module (exact location is `node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:187`) :

```
Connection.prototype.query = function query(sql, values, cb) { 
  (... some lines of code here ...)
  if (!(typeof sql === 'object' && 'typeCast' in sql)) {
     query.typeCast = this.config.typeCast;
   }
  (... some lines of code here ...)
}
```

The related snippet in my code is as follows :

```
async function mcSeekAllItems(connection) {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM `books`';
    return util.promisify(connection.query).call(sql)
        .then(
            results => results
        ).catch(
            error => console.log("Error 006 : ", error)
        );
}
```

Since I am not familiar with the internals of the `mysql` module, I am not sure what I have done wrong here.
The full source code for my Node project is at https://github.com/ewan-delanoy/node_app

The error is trigerred by requesting the `books/` URL in a browser.
And here goes the full error message :

```
$ node app.js
Serving on port 3000
Error 006 :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined
    at String.query (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:185:34)
    at internal/util.js:278:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at String.query (internal/util.js:277:12)
    at Object.mcSeekAllItems [as seekAllItems] (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/models/book.js:83:45)
    at /Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/app.js:26:34
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ewandelanoy/Teuliou/Sites/Gwerzher_Leoriou/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```